# What is the best way to display Flash messages in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I have nodejs app in Ejs framework , I'am a newbie to java script, 
I need to know what is the correct way to set flash messages in Node.js

**My Code given below throws me an error ,like this :**

```html
C:\Users\sad\Desktop\Node Application\routes\users.js:57
      req.flash('error_mesg', 'A User with this name already exisit !!')
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'flash' of null
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\as\Desktop\Node Application\routes\users.js:57:10)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\sa\Desktop\Node Application\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Node Application\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Node Application\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Here goes my code where I initiate everything :**

```html
var flash = require('connect-flash');

// Global VArs
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});
```

**And here goes my Code where I really apply it :**

```js
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
  res.render('register' ,{
    errors:errors
  })
}else{

   var newUser = {first_name,last_name, role,email,password,company,role}
   request({
       url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/dashboard/register/",
       method: "POST",
       json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
       body: newUser
   }, function (req, res, err, body){
      var status = res['statusCode']
       console.log(typeof(status));
       if (status = '400'){
       req.flash('error_mesg', 'A User with this name already exisit !!')


}

   });
 }
```

There some related answers to this type of question but not specifically flash messages .

Here goes my html :`{{#if error_msg}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}</div>
        {{/if}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the last bit of code you posted is the body of an express endpoint, I'm guessing you overwrote your express callback variables `req` and `res` in your callback to `request`. Also, that is not the current function signature for the `request` library callback, it should be `function (error, response, body)`, not `function (req, res, err, body)`. Fix the function signature, use unique variable names and it should work:

```
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
  res.render('register' ,{
    errors:errors
  })
}else{
   var newUser = {first_name,last_name, role,email,password,company,role}
   request({
       url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/dashboard/register/",
       method: "POST",
       json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
       body: newUser
   }, function (error, response, body){
       var status = response.statusCode;
       console.log(typeof(status));
       if (status = '400'){
       req.flash('error_mesg', 'A User with this name already exisit !!')
   });
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Rob it works fine but some times it gives me an error like **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

Comment: That might happen if there is more code than what you posted, it occurs when you call some variant of `res.send` more than one time. Make sure you don't have any instances of `res.send` being called more than once and that error should go away